# How to install cloudflare on cPanel Servers?

Tags: apache, cpanel, cloudflare

I am trying to recompile Apache using easyapache on cPanel Server but the mod_clouflare has disappeared from the Exhaustive Options List. How to install cloudflare on cPanel Server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Installation on cPanel Servers**

To integrate mod_cloudflare to EasyApache so that it can be easily included from the cPanel web interface and remain activated in Apache httpd after rebuilds:

```
# wget https://www.cloudflare.com/static/misc/mod_cloudflare/cloudflare.pl
# perl cloudflare.pl install
```

Alternatively:

```
# perl <(curl -s https://www.cloudflare.com/static/misc/mod_cloudflare/cloudflare.pl) install
```

Now the checkbox "Mod CloudFlare" should appear on the Exhaustive Options List.

Source: https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads